# Modeling an OLAP cube for Football analysis

Tags: ssas, olap, dimensional-modeling

I would like to do a basic analysis on NFL Football data by season. For example, the `Fact` that I would like to have would be:

`[NFL Fact]`

- Season (Dimension)
- Team (Dimension)
- Coach (Dimension)
- Roster (Dimension, one-to-many, can be the same 'Person' dimension as for Coach)
- Wins (Int)
- Losses (Int)
- Ties (Int)
- Made_Playoffs (Bool)
- Won_Conference (Bool)
- Won_Superbowl (Bool)

And example of the data would look like this in a human-readable form:

In the **2019** season 
the **Kansas City Chiefs** team 
coached by **Andy Reid** 
who had on their roster **Patrick Mahomes**, **Travis Kelce**, ... 
had **12** wins 
and **4** losses 
and **0** ties in the regular season 
**made** the playoffs 
and **won** their conference 
and **won** the Super Bowl.

If the above is our fact table, how could the dimensions be modeled? Here is my first stab at it:

---

`Season`

- Year (key)
- AFC Champion (string or link to dimension? Example: "DAL")
- NFC Champion (string or link to dimension? Example: "DAL")
- NFL Champion (string or link to dimension? Example: "DAL" or should it be "2018 DAL" ?)

**Question**: should the AFC/NFC/NFL Champion be a string? Or should this reference a `Team` dimension? Why would one choice be made over the other?

---

`Team`

- Code (String, example: "DAL")
- Season (Int, example: 2018, key = code+year, example: "2018 DAL")
- Conference (String, example: "AFC")
- Division (String, example: "South")
- Name (String, example: "Dallas Cowboys")
- URL (String, example: "https://nfl.com/dallas-cowboys")

**Question**: do I need to make the key be Code+Year, or can I just use the Code since the season is 'derived' from the Fact table it is linked to? Should the `Season` be an Integer or link to the Season dimension?

---

`Person` (includes both players, coaches, etc.)

- Name
- Season
- Team (?)
- Position
- Age
- College

**Question**: do I need to include the `Team` here, or is that not needed because the team is already inferred from the fact table? Should the Season be linked here as well?

---

Any suggestions on the above format would be most helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at NFL Football, but can give you basic ideas how to manage your entities and create relations.

First of all consider fact table as a main manager and connector between all dimensions.

[Team] dimension can possibly be Slowly Changing Type-2 (SCD-2) because you may want to track changes of teams between divisions/conferences etc. Or even name change. But to get seasonal info for a team you need only to join [NFL Fact] and [Team], so no need to create Code+Year key as Season attribute.

[Season] in your example looks like not a dimension, but a datamart over [NFL Fact]. Because every row of [Season] you can get querying [NFL Fact]. AFC/NFC/NFL Champion you can get from it + Conference attribute of [Team] dimension. I suggest to create [Date] dimension with the list of dates (years or YYYYMMDD or else) instead of [Season].

[Person] you can't get from [NFL Fact]. Because the lowest granularity in [NFL Fact] is actually a Team. So to manage players/coaches you need a separate fact table (because next year player can move to another team etc.). So it will be [Persons] fact table with surrogate keys of a team that they play for a given year. This also means that Coach/Roster attributes to be a part of this new [Persons] fact table instead if [NFL Fact], because in your example [NFL Fact] is only to collect team stats.